# Is this proof that $\sin(x^2)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the result specifically with epsilon-delta, rather than composition of continuous functions.

We are to prove:

$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R} \forall \epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}(0 < |x-c| < \delta \rightarrow |\sin(x^2)-\sin(c^2)| < \epsilon)$$

Since $\sin(x^2)-\sin(c^2) \leq 2|\sin(\frac{x^2-c^2}{2})| \leq |x^2 - c^2|$, if we can find a $\delta$ such that $|x-c| < \delta \rightarrow |x^2 - c^2| < \epsilon$, we are done.

Take $\delta = \min\{\frac{\epsilon}{|3c|},|c|\}$. Then we have $|x-c|<\delta \rightarrow x < |c|+c \leq |2c|$. This means that $\frac{\epsilon}{|3c|} < \frac{\epsilon}{|x+c|}$. But we have by assumption that $|x-c| < \frac{\epsilon}{|3c|}$, hence we have

$$|x-c| < \delta \rightarrow |x-c|< \frac{\epsilon}{|x+c|} \rightarrow |x-c||x+c| < \epsilon \rightarrow |x^2 - c^2| < \epsilon$$

and hence $|\sin(x^2) - \sin(c^2)|<\epsilon$ and the proof is complete. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

I am specifically looking to see if my logic with the choice of $\delta$ is correct, and if it works with the modulus signs. In particular, I wasn't quite sure the best way forward for relating the terms $|x-c||x+c|$ and $|x-c|$, since the product being larger or smaller depends on how close $x$ is to $c$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ah, I forgot about that. I suppose I can just take any null sequence from the left and right $\{x_n\}$, and it follows that since sine is strictly monotone in a neighbourhood of zero and $\{f(x_n)\}$ is bounded above (or below) the result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments -

1. The unnamed algebraic trig identity should be stated. After this is used, the main issue you have is actually just about the continuity of $x^2$ (which is similar in spirit to the "composition of continuous is continuous" result you are avoiding)
2. If $c=0$, then your choice of $\delta$ is apparently $0$. This is not allowed. Further, $\frac1{|c|}(=\infty?)$ appears in the following lines; you should always be afraid of dividing by zero.
3. You have proven $x+c \le 3|c|$. Why does this imply $|x+c|\le 3|c|$?

Here's a fix. From $|x|\le |c|+|x-c|\le |c|+\delta$,
$$|x+c| \le |x|+|c| \le 2|c|+\delta.$$
Now let
$$\delta = \min (1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|c|+1}).$$
See if you can finish.

Comment: Thank you! This choice of $\delta$ is very nice. I am guessing there is no way to rectify my approach? Points 1 and 2 are relatively easy to fix, but I can't see a way to fix point 3 right?

Comment: @masiewpao, yes I think that’s right